# Keyboard is behaving wrong in Dell XPS 13 DE after Startup

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, dell-xps, keymap

After startup, I got wrong output when I pressed some keys.

- `3` -> `34`/`43`
- `d` -> `df`/`fd`
- `v` -> `cv`/`vc`

And some other keys.

After few minutes. problem was fixed automatically.

It happens every time when I start my Laptop

> OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Is your keyboard set to the right region and layout?

Comment: Yes. I have checked those part

Comment: The errors are all related to one pair of adjacent columns of the keyboard matrix.  Interesting that E & R aren't affected.  It's possible that the ribbon cable from the top of the keyboard is slightly off in the connector or some dirt or liquid is affecting things.  The keyboard decoder circuit could also be failing.  Try plugging in an external keyboard.  If that doesn't have a problem, it's in your keyboard.